# add qt and qt mobility to my project

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I've been reading about qt for some time now and would like to use it to write application for Nokia devices. But there is one thing unclear for me. Let say my aplication uses qt and qt mobility so anyone who would like to install it would have to install qt and qt mobility manually first. Am I getting it right? Or maybe there is a way to add them to my project as static libraries or something...thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using QT creator??? or which IDE are you using???

Comment: Yes I'm using QT creator

Answer (score 1):

Nokia Smart Installer eliminates the need for Symbian apps to bundle the Qt framework in distributed SIS files. When an app packaged with Smart Installer is installed, a check is made for the presence of the required Qt packages. If any Qt packages are not present Smart Installer downloads and installs them.

Comment: Thanks ... does the Smart Install downloads and install also 'qt mobility'

Comment: ok got the answer http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Nokia_Smart_Installer_for_Symbian

Answer (score 0):

You need download the qt-mobility source code and compile it,

See [QtMobility 1.2.2: Installation Guide](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html)